# What are the consequences of varchar?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a MySQL database and I am wondering about the consequences of the `varchar` size on my query performances.

For example, what would be the difference between a `varchar(10)` and a `varchar(50)` in terms of the performances or database size.

If I have something like 10000 rows, would it affect a lot on performances or is it insignificant?

**Note :** I don't do any join on this column (if that is important)

Comment: Not doing joins on that column may be part of the equation.  My experience is with that few rows (10,000), the size of your varchar will have little impact.  Of more consequence is being sure to have good indexes.

Comment: @Tagazok . . . The performance depends on whether character positions 11-50 are ever filled in.  If the data is the same, performance should not be affected by the maximum size (for two sizes less than 256).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`varchar(10)` means that maximum allowed bytes is 10 and `varchar(50)` means that maximum allowed bytes is 50. Basically, a varchar(10) is no different disk-wise than a varchar(128).So, in whatever manner you declare your columns, it wont make a difference on the storage end. But it will certainly make a difference while making a query.

From the [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can
>   be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to
>   65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a
>   VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size
>   (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character
>   set used.

Comment: Ok, so, considering there is no joins at all on this column, is there any difference in term of performances if I store a long string rather than a short one? I am wondering if I should store something like "tsk_put" or "task_updated" (it is a table that store notifications). Also, at some point, it will be more than 10000 rows...

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any real difference in performances between a `VARCHAR(10)` and `VARCHAR(50)`.

The real difference would be between `CHAR` and `VARCHAR`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

> The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare
>   when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255.
>   When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the
>   specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are
>   removed.
>
> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can
>   be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to
>   65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a
>   VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size
>   (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character
>   set used. See Section E.7.4, “Limits on Table Column Count and Row
>   Size”.

---

Replacing *every* `VARCHAR` by `CHAR` columns *might* improve performances, since then, rows will have fixed size, thus reducing fragmentation and somehow optimizing disks access.

That being said, if you have only 10000 rows, I doubt you would see any real difference, unless maybe if you have unusually "long" rows.

Comment: *"There should be any real difference in performances between a VARCHAR(10) and VARCHAR(50)."* -- Shoudn't that be: *"There **shouldn't** be any real difference..."*

Comment: @PetrR. Of course, it was a stupid ... hum ... typo ... This is fixed now. Thank you ;)